# Менять текст кнопки при нажатии на другую кнопку в Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Я пишу программу "Викторина". Мне нужно чтобы каждый раз когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, которая называется "GO", картинка, которая и является вопросом видоизменялась. При этом должны меняться и варианты ответа. То есть текст кнопок должен меняться каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку "GO". В дальнейшем я планирую использовать случайную выборку из списка, но в данный момент мне необходимо просто понять как видоизменять текст кнопок и картинку отталкиваясь от нажатия кнопки "GO". Я написал программу, но она не работает. Я использую Kivy/Python. Код предоставлен ниже. Я убрал все не нужные части кода, чтобы сделать его минимальным для восприятия. Также можете посмотреть комментарии в коде, где я указал на важные составляющие и ключевые проблемы. Скорее всего я что то делаю не так, так как моя функция никак не видоизменяет данные которые необходимо изменить. Детально я указал все в комментариях ниже. Прошу помогите решить эту задачу.

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')


class Quiz(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Quiz, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (900, 600)
        self.cols = 1

        self.im = Image(source="picture1.png") # сюда я добавляю первую картинку, которая будет показываться как пример. Ниже в коде я пытаюсь прописать функцию которая будет изменять эту начальную картинку на другую. 
        self.im.size_hint = (0.50, 0.50)
        self.im.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.80}
        self.add_widget(self.im)

        self.app_text = Label(font_size='16',
                          text="Find correct answer!",
                          color='white',
                          halign='center')
        self.app_text.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.65}

        self.add_widget(self.app_text)

        # У меня есть 4 кнопки, которые в начале имеют пустое строковое значение. Ниже в коде я пытаюсь прописать функцию, которая при вызове сможет поменять текстовое значение этих кнопок. 
        self.button1 = Button(text='', background_color='#F62C3F')
        self.button2 = Button(text='', background_color='#F62C3F')
        self.button3 = Button(text='', background_color='#F62C3F')
        self.button4 = Button(text='', background_color='#F62C3F')

        self.button_go = Button(text='GO', background_color='#04D0F9')

        self.button1.size_hint = (0.15, 0.05)
        self.button2.size_hint = (0.15, 0.05)
        self.button3.size_hint = (0.15, 0.05)
        self.button4.size_hint = (0.15, 0.05)
    
        self.button_go.size_hint = (0.15, 0.05)

        self.button1.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.4, "center_y": 0.54}
        self.button2.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.4, "center_y": 0.48}
        self.button3.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 0.54}
        self.button4.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 0.48}
    
        self.button_go.pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.36}

        self.button_go.bind(on_press=self.next_question) # это та самая кнопка, при нажатии которой я хочу вызывать функцию с помощью которой я смогу изменить картинку и текст кнопок. 

        self.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.add_widget(self.button3)
        self.add_widget(self.button4)
    
        self.add_widget(self.button_go)

    # Та самая функция с помощью которой я хочу изменить текст и картинку. В данный момент функция абсолютно не рабочая. В этом и заключается главная проблема. 
    def next_question(self, instance):
        self.im = Image(source="picture_2.png")
        self.button1 = Button(text='A', background_color='#F62C3F')
        self.button2 = Button(text='B', background_color='#F62C3F')
        self.button3 = Button(text='C', background_color='#F62C3F')
        self.button4 = Button(text='D', background_color='#F62C3F')
```

Answer (score 0):

Во 1 прописывай все виджеты(кнопки и тд) и их расположение в отдельном файле с расширение kv.
Во 2 когда ты будешь прописывать кнопки в отдельном файле с расширение kv) ты можешь присвоить им id (посмотри примеры в документации, вот например про кнопки https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html?highlight=button) и в твоей методе next_question ты можешь обратиться к id кнопки например такие образом self.root.ids.ТВОЙ ID.text = НОВОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
В 3 моя рекомендация используй KivyMD он банально красивее)